# How can I input the position of multiple points into an OSL shader and store them in an array?

Tags: scripting, osl

This is my setup.

[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I store all those position vectors in the vecs array?

Comment: Can we ask what this is for? I (personally) can't imagine any way to store shared data between calls on the OSL node per-shading-point, other than externally ( say, in a texture ? )  The output of the Attribute node will return a single vector, evalutated on the shading-point, every time the node is called.

Comment: @RobinBetts I'm trying to recreate this effect: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZBfLgfsvSk

Comment: Tgis can be done in GN simulation:  https://entagma.com/geometry-node-simulation-advect-by-curl-noise/ .. but you want it in a shader?